# Search multiple custom fields by using meta_query

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, wp-query, customization, search

I'm trying to create a search results listing for a custom post type and the problem I'm running in to is with the way the 'meta_query' parameter is stringing the passed values together.  It appears to be treating each 'meta_query' value as an 'AND' rather than 'OR'.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
$strsearch = 'lorem';
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array('key' => '_product_make','compare' => 'LIKE','value' => $strsearch),
        array('key' => '_product_model','compare' => 'LIKE','value' => $strsearch)
        )
    ,'s' => $strsearch);
$resource_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

When I search anyone of the fields individually I get the desired results.  When I use them together it comes up as not found since the string I'm searching for may only occur in one of the three fields listed below.  Is there any way to have 'meta_query' treat each of the passed field comparisons as 'OR'?

Comment: Great question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, since WP 3.2 you can set the 'relation' arg:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array('key' => '_product_make','compare' => 'LIKE','value' => $strsearch),
    array('key' => '_product_model','compare' => 'LIKE','value' => $strsearch)
)
```

See http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17011

Comment: Is it possible to do now? I've looked at the ticket and it seems to say "solved", but I can't figure out what to add to make it work. Would really appreciate any help. Thanks :)

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: @dashaluna: You're welcome. Note that on this site, the appropriate response is to upvote the answer. :)

Comment: when i use this it seems to not search the normal fields? Seems 's' => $strsearch is ignored completely but 'relation' => 'OR' works perfectly with the meta_keys... Is it possible to search the default fields too? (title etc)

Comment: I wonder if this will match searches like this:

A post with:

`custom_field_1` contains the word `cats`

`custom_field_2` contains the word `dogs`

Someone searches for `ats ogs` and the post is returned.