# Custom search with meta fields

Tags: custom-field, search

I made a custom search form with text fields and dropdown.

Now, my form is in its own template file - sidebar-search.php.

I have also made the searchform.php which should get the data from sidebar and then display results.

I'm using [this method](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13664/search-multiple-custom-fields-by-using-meta-query) for the query.

**My problem** is this: When I put the "action" to "bloginfo('home')" - nothing happens.
When I put the "action" to "TEMPLATEPATH . 'searchform.php'" - shows a blank page.
(this is now updated - see last lines)

Here is the code from searchform.php. Here is the sidebar-search (removed links, check update at the bottom)

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
I now placed my code in search.php, and here is how it looks like: [link](http://pastie.org/5459128)

It still just reloads the page and no results are shown.
My action is now like this:  `action="<?php echo get_bloginfo('home') ?>"`

Answer (score 0):

I think that your main problem is that you are trying to display the results with  **searchform.php**. That is basically just the form for the search, which you don't need since you have your own form in the sidebar (if I understand you correctly).

The results of a WP search are displayed with "**search.php**"

Comment: I have updated the question. I put the code in search.php, but now it just reloads home page